# Where to store selectted list items?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a list (array) of items. They are as `Input()` parameter for component.

User can make drag-drop sortring in this list and select some elements.

Where to store these selected elements to be able restore statemenet after reflesh page?

Should I create another array? If yes, how then set relations between list and array of selected items?

How do you solve this regular task in case when it should be reusable with some different lists?

Comment: do you want your selected element to remain as it is even if you refresh the page?

Comment: If you want to maintain the preferences of your application even after closing and refresh then you should save objects in your browser local storage.

Comment: Could you explain architecture of component, service?

Comment: I try to create a unified component that works with different lists, sorte them, select any and unselect. Is there a good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use React and React Native but the concept would be the same I'd imagine regardless.

I use state management with `Redux`.  Depending on the type of data you are working with obviously depends but what is sounds like is what I would do in your situation is store the original state information (list of data) in some portion of my Redux state slice.

I'd then have a copy of that original state slice that is used in the `Input` component that I have.  I can make as many changes as I want on that copy as much as I'd like without impacting the original data.  And then on some user action let's call is a "Save" I can update that original state with the new values with some action or function call.  In my case updating the state slice would cause my component to re-render and show the updated information but I'm sure a similiar concept is possible is Angular

Edit:

Again, not sure how Angular works specifically by passing information from one component down to the next via props or if a component directly needs a specific slice of `Redux` to function you can subscribe to that specific slice using a `hook` (functional component) or using `connect` (for class components).

But basically you pass the state in the way you need it.  Inside the component you would make your duplicate copy that you will use that will persist as long as needed.  Upon a user performing some action you would let `Redux` state to update properly by performing an `action` and handling the information hand off via a `reducer`.

I can't say I know the best state management to use for Angular someone else can chime in better for that but hopefully this gives you some idea of thinking in terms of handling data in general.

Comment: Could you explain architecture of component, service? Where is logic to set/get item?

Comment: Let is assume I store selected items in service.

Comment: I try to create a unified component that works with different lists, sort then, select all and unselect. Is there a good example?